# How to Force Focus Loss on a Textbox when a button is pushed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a pretty large wpf aplication that is built using the prism framework and MVVM concepts and if a user types a change into a textbox and presses the accept button without leaving the textbox first it causes the button action to not receive the changed values in the textbox.  My viewmodel has the following button code

```
private DelegateCommand<string> _myButtonAction;
public ICommand MyButtonAction
{
   get
   {
      if (_myButtonAction== null)
      {
         _myButtonAction= DelegateCommand<string>.FromAsyncHandler(
                    MyFunction,
                    s => true);
      }

      return _myButtonAction;
   }
}

private Task MyFunction(string arg)
{
   // this event calls a button.focus in the view 
   EventAggregator.GetEvent<FocusObject>().Publish("");
   // this doesn't work either
   Keyboard.ClearFocus();
   using (new WaitCursor("my function"))
   {
       // do some stuff
   }
   return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Despite trying a Keyboard.ClearFocus() and using a message event to call a MyButton.Focus(); in the view nothing seems to trigger the Textbox to lose focus once I am in this method.  Does anyone else have any suggestions for how to force an update of a bunch of textboxes (lets say 100+) from a viewmodel?

Comment: what's the main purpose of losing focus? to update the text in the TextBox?

Comment: Correct.  The textboxes are set to UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" as is the default, and with this many textboxes and as much validation as I have I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: Ah,alright. I was going to suggest to do it onpropertychanged. Another option for you is to set it to Explicit, then invoke that once everything is done (instead of trying to lose focus).

Comment: Do you know a clean way to do an explicit set on a bunch of textboxes?

Comment: @PlTaylor Could you give an example of how your TextBoxes are bound to your ViewModel? My bigger question is: are you sure the bound properties for all of your TextBoxes are being set in the ViewModel already? For example: does switching between them, which definitely causes focus to change, update the property you have each one bound to?

Comment: Yes, if I place a breakpoint in the setter of my viewmodel it is tripped and set correctly when I switch focus manually before I press the button.

Comment: Focus is a concern of the UI.  Have you tried just adding an event handler to the button and handling it in the codebehind?

Comment: @PlTaylor how are you binding the texboxes to your ViewModel right now? Do you also have 100 different, individual properties?

Comment: @Will I have tried this and despite the event firing and focusing on the button, the focus does not appear to be taken away from the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

The sources of data for the TextBoxes are not being told to update.

I see that you are concerned about using `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` for validation reasons. However, I believe that to be a great solution for this problem still. To keep the TextBoxes from forcing validation with every keystroke you could add a [Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) to your binding.

For example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding someProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Delay=100}" />
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply this via a style or something similar?

Comment: How are you currently setting the text for all of your TextBoxes? If it is in the DataTemplate for a list of some sort it should not be too much work to add the Delay. On the other hand, if you are setting the binding individually for 100 TextBoxes you might just have bite the bullet and change them all.

Comment: Yeah, it is individually.